# mssql_execute returns no results - better way to debug?

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

My connection is established, and I can call my stored procedure:

```
$pid = $_GET['pid'];
$conn = mssql_connect($server, $username, $password);
...
mssql_select_db('mydb',$conn);

$sproc = mssql_init('consultGetPatientData');
mssql_bind($sproc, '@pid', $pid, SQLINT2);

$result = mssql_execute($sproc);
echo mssql_num_rows($result);
if($result){    
    $row = mssql_fetch_assoc($result);      
...
```

My `$pid` value is being passed correctly. 
The `$result` value being is `var_dump`:

```
resource(3) of type (mssql result)
```

And `msql_num_rows($result)` yields 0 rows.

The user connecting to the database has sufficient access to the `consultGetPatientData` stored procedure:

[image: Properties]

When I manually run the stored procedure, desired results are being returned. My

My questions:

**Is there a better way to debug these types of errors?**

**Is there anything glaring I am missing?**

Thank you.

EDIT: stored procedure code as requested:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[consultGetPatientData] 
    @pid int = 0    
AS
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

select 
    pd.pid, 
    pd.external_id,
    pd.fname, 
    pd.lname, 
    pd.DOB, 
    pd.ss, 
    pd.sex,
    pd.allergies,
    pb.date,
    pb.release
from 
    patient_data pd 
        inner join patient_booking_data pb on pd.pid = pb.pid
where 
    pd.pid = @pid
    and pb.date in (
        select MAX(date) from patient_booking_data where pid = @pid
    )
END
```

Comment: Show me your SP code...

Comment: Added the stored procedure.

Comment: When debugging I like to log every thing using error_log() also you can wrap your code inside of try-catch block.

Comment: mssql_execute does'nt return a result...you should use mssql_query instead...i'm going to post my answer

Comment: I'm not sure as to why the downvote? Anyone care to explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
$sproc = mssql_init('consultGetPatientData');
mssql_bind($sproc, '@pid', $pid, SQLINT2);

$result = mssql_execute($sproc);
echo mssql_num_rows($result);
```

To this:

```
$result=mssql_query("consultGetPatientData ".$pid.""); 
echo mssql_num_rows($result);

while($arr = mssql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
 echo $arr['sex']."</br>"; 
 //you can put the rest of the code to display the rest of the fields
}
```

Comment: Interesting, Robert. The user of `mssql_query` worked, rather than using `mssql_execute`. This same code is deployed on another remote server, and the use of `execute` works just fine. Regardless, your answer worked. Thank you.